# Get database version in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I sometimes connect to a 3.2 database, and sometimes to a 2.7 database, depending on deployment. Occasionally, there is a feature which is available on 3.2 but not 2.7 so I need to check the version. Here is what I have tried, [based on the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.version/).

```
> Meteor.users.rawDatabase().version()
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'version'
```

How do you get the database version in meteor?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`RemoteCollectionDriver`](https://forums.meteor.com/t/issue-using-remotecollectiondriver-and-exposing-collection-to-common-code/3145) to access a the underlying [node.js native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Admin.html) and then use the admin database for the operation:

```
const adminDb = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.admin()
adminDb.buildInfo( (err, info) => { console.log(info.version); })
```